# Liquid XML 2017 update problems

Tags: liquid-xml

There is a serious problem with the new update of the Liquid Xml and i can't figure it out.

1. When open a new xml file by clicking on it i receive the error:
   "There was a problem sending the command to the program." and then
   the file is open.
2. When trying to validate an xml file with a schema i receive errors that elements are not found. Doing the same validation with
   LiquidXml on another computer all is fine. How can i downgrade this
   version because is not OK.

Comment: These issues have been resolved in v15.0.2 available for download from our web site or via the Auto-update function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. We have seen this on some PCs, it looks like a DDE timeout issue which we are working on a resolution. We see the file does actually open, but Windows shows the error as you describe. Is this what you see, or does the file not open either?
2. Do you have a specific schema, or any schema? E.g. if you open the sample project and open the BookStoreSample.xml and press F7 do you get the issue?

If you want to uninstall, you can do so using the 'Change or remove a program' from Windows Control Panel. You can then download and install the 2016 version:

https://www.liquid-technologies.com/my-downloads

Note: you need to login as the user who purchased the license.

Comment: This entire conversation feels like it should be on your own support forum, though, not on Stack Overflow

Comment: I've done eventually a downgrade of the product because it is used in production. Thank for reply.